# Why are my CSS star layers not aligning % properly?

Tags: html, css

I want to display 55% exactly

Could anyone help complete this? Or at least point to the right direction?

it does not display 55% correctly

This is my code:

```css
.coupon{
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    color: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.get-code{
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background: #f90;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 14px 15px 14px 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    min-width: 55%;
    text-align: left;
}

.get-code:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 44px solid transparent;
    border-left: 44px solid #f90;
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    top: 0;
}
.get-code:hover{
    padding-right:5px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon"> <a href="/"> 
<span class="code-text">DFDSEFEF</span> 
<span class="get-code">Get Code</span></a></div>
```

```
min-width: 55%;
```

wrong operation

[image]

I want it to look like

[image]

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to better explain, or possibly post an image of what you expect the code you provided should look like. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It seems like your coupon code is to short, if you would have made it longer you would get the desired outcome. Either that, or give the text within the code-text block a lot of `padding-left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help.

```css
.coupon{
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    color: #444;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.get-code{
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background: #f90;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 14px 15px 14px 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    min-width: 45%;
    text-align: left;
}

.get-code:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 44px solid transparent;
    border-left: 44px solid #f90;
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    top: 0;
}
.get-code:hover{
    padding-right:5px !important;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 16px; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon"> 
  <a href="/"> 
  <span class="code-text">DFDSEFEF</span> 
  <span class="get-code">Get Code</span></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
**1. Your padding affect the actual width. try use `calc`.**

```
.get-code{
   padding: 14px 15px 14px 14px;
}
```

here the padding on right and left is `15px` and `14px`, so your width will be:

```
.get-code{
   padding: 14px 15px 14px 14px;
   width: calc(55% - 15px - 14px)
}
```

**2. if you want it exact `55%`, use `width`, don't use `min-width`**

Here is the full code:

```
.get-code{
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background: #f90;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 14px 15px 14px 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: calc(55% - 15px - 14px)
    text-align: left;
}
```

but it will break the text because not enough width, my suggestion is add width to the `.coupon` element, or make the `GET CODE` font size smaller.